# how to build paths and responses object for a url

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-2.0, openapi-generator

i would like to create the path object for the following url

```
url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
```

in the code when the user enters the above mentioned url followed by slash \ a method called start() is to be called and executed.
that method when called it receives response from the backend in form of json file and it retuens it.

how to build the path and responses object for such action please

**code**:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'] )
def startCoord2():

baseURL = "https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car?api_key=5b3ce3597851110001cf62480ecf8c403567479a87de01df5da651fb&start=8.681436,49.414554&end=8.681561,49.414747"

with urllib.request.urlopen(baseURL) as response:
    print ("str(response): " + str(response))
    print ("str(response.getCode(): " + str(response.getcode()))
    data = response.read()
    print ("response.read(): " + str(data))
    dataAsJSONObject = json.loads(data)
    distance = str(dataAsJSONObject["features"][0]['properties']['segments'][0]['distance'])
return dataAsJSONObject #config['EndPoint']['url'] + config['EndPoint']['api_key'] + "&start=" + startLat + "," + startLng + "&end=" + end1Lat + "," + endLng + ""
```

**yaml file**:

```
openapi: '3.0.2'
info:
  title: &apiTitle "Distance micro-service API."
  description: "This micro-service receives four comma separated GPS coordinates in the following order, startLongitude, startLatitude, endLongitude
               , endLatitude in the url. Then it receives a response in a form of json file. The json file is to be fetched for the distance which represents the distance between 
               the aforementioned GPS coordinates"
  version: '1.0'
  termsOfService: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/getDistance/terms"
  contact:
    name: " "
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
    email: "me@provider.com"
  license:
    name: "CC Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 (CC BY-SA 4.0)"
    url: "https://openweathermap.org/price"
servers:
  - url: http://127.0.0.1:5000
    description: Local host test server. When accessed it will return the distance from Berlin to Alexandria in Egypt in kilometers.
    variables:
      originAndDestinationGPSCoords:
        default: 13.404954,52.520008,29.924526,31.205753
        description: 
          Local host test server. When accessed it will return the distance from Berlin to Alexandria in Egypt in kilometers.
paths:
  /:
    get:
      tags:
        - "get response data in json format"
      summary: 
         get the distance between 8.681436,49.414554,8.681561,49.414747
      description: > 
        to display data in json formate
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Distance fetched successfully.
```

Comment: Please add more details. What exactly are you trying to do, with what technology? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Software2 please see the update of the question posted

Comment: You've tagged this with swagger-ui, but that's a documentation tool and the code you've linked has nothing to do with that. You've also tagged this with swagger-2.0, but you've posted an OpenAPI 3.0 spec. If your openapi-generator tag is accurate, why haven't you just fed your spec file into it? Please clarify what it is you're trying to do, I do not understand.

Comment: looks like you are using flask. But your usecase is not clear, what exactly you want to achieve. I can see that your root path serves as an API which when invoked, it inturn invokes a different URL (here BaseURL) using urllib.request.urlopen and extract the JSON from the response of that URL and returns the main response for your API. BUT WHERE IS OPENAPI3 INVOLVED IN HERE ?